# Find nearby cities using Geocoding API

Tags: php, laravel, google-geocoding-api

Is it possible to search nearby cities with given city or latitude longitude using geocoding API?

For example user input `City A`, then the result is a list of cities nearby to city A.

if not possible, do you have any suggestions for using other APIs or references that can be used?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What you should use is **[Nearby Search](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/places/web-service/search-nearby?hl=en)** using **[Places API](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/places/web-service/overview)**.

You can use the [`radius`](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/places/web-service/search-nearby?hl=en#radius) parameter to limit the distance of nearby search and also specify the [`types`](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/places/web-service/search-nearby?hl=en#type) parameter depending on what you want or need.

You can use these types on their Table 3:

1. `(regions)` type collection instructs the Places service to return any
   result matching the following types:

> - locality
> - sublocality
> - postal_code
> - country
> - administrative_area_level_1
> - administrative_area_level_2

1. `(cities)` type collection instructs the Places service to return results that match `locality` or `administrative_area_level_3`.

Ref: [Table 3: Type collections supported in Place Autocomplete requests](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/places/web-service/supported_types#table3)

I recommend that you should read more from their docs if you want to learn more. here's the link to get started: [Places API Docs](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/places/web-service/overview)

Hope this helps.

Comment: its only return selected location not with nearby. `params: location:-7.546839,112.226479,radius:100000, type:administrative_area_level_2`

Comment: You could only use `regions` or `cities` as types. Here's an example: `https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/place/nearbysearch/json?&location=-7.546839,112.226479&radius=100000&type=cities&key=YOUR_API_KEY`

Comment: According to the [docs](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/places/web-service/supported_types#table3:~:text=Note%3A%20The%20types%20below%20are%20not%20supported%20in%20the%20type%20filter%20of%20a%20place%20search.), `administrative_area_level_2` is not supported as `type` filter on this Place Search.

Comment: Only give `locality` data on my country, and in another country, some give  `cities` data some only `locality`, and some mix between `locality` data and  `cities` data

Comment: That's because not all nations exhibit the same administrative levels. The API isn't guaranteed to return any particular component for an address within their data set. What may be thought of as the city, such as Brooklyn, may not show up as `locality`, but rather as another component - in this case, `sublocality_level_1`.  ref: [docs](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/geocoding/requests-geocoding#Types:~:text=The%20Geocoding%20API%20isn%27t,components%20from%20the%20response.)